# Type error of getting average by id in KDB

Tags: kdb

I am trying make a function for the aggregate consumption by mid in a kdb+ table (aggregate value by mid). Also this table is being imported from a csv file like this:
table: ("JJP";enlist",")0:`:data.csv

Where the meta data is for the table columns is:
mid is type long(j), value(j) is type long and ts is type timestamp (p).

[image: data of the table]

Here is my function:
agg: {select avg value by mid from table}
but I get the
'type
[0]  get select avg value by mid from table

[image: error message]

But the type of value is type long (j). So I am not sure why I can't get the avg I also tried this with type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value can't be used as a column name because it is keyword used in kdb+. Renaming the column should correct the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`value` is a keyword and should not be used as a column name.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/value/

You can remove it as a column name using `.Q.id`

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qid-sanitize

```
q)t:flip`value`price!(1 2;1 2)
q)t
value price
-----------
1     1
2     2
q)t:.Q.id t
q)t
value1 price
------------
1      1
2      2
```

Or `xcol`

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cols/#xcol

```
q)(enlist[`value]!enlist[`val]) xcol t
val price
---------
1   1
2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the value column as you read it:

```
flip`mid`val`ts!("JJP";",")0:`:data.csv
```

Comment: This will parse the header row as a normal row of data so user will want to drop off the first row using `1 _` https://code.kx.com/q/ref/drop/

Comment: Yes, good catch! Wrote without testing